# SET_ITEM_PROPERTY on INITIAL_VALUE not working

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Using the following code, I'm trying to set the property of `INITIAL_VALUE` in the form field named `STATUS` depending on the condition. The following code is on `PRE-TEXT-ITEM` trigger.

```
BEGIN
    IF (:LOAN.STATUS = 'A') THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY(:LOAN.STATUS,INITIAL_VALUE,'Active');
    ELSIF (:LOAN.STATUS = 'I') THEN
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY(:LOAN.STATUS,INITIAL_VALUE,'Inactive');
    END IF;
END;
```

Putting the following code outside of the condition doesn't work as well.

```
SET_ITEM_PROPERTY(:LOAN.STATUS,INITIAL_VALUE,'Active');
```

Please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referring Forms' help, seen that there's no such `property`(second argument) `INITIAL_VALUE` for `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY` method. Instead, you might assign the desired value for the item directly in `PRE-TEXT-ITEM` trigger as below :

```
BEGIN 
    IF   (:LOAN.STATUS = 'A') THEN 
          :LOAN.STATUS := 'Active';
    ELSIF (:LOAN.STATUS = 'I') THEN 
          :LOAN.STATUS := 'Inactive';
    END IF;
END;
```

or abbreviately fill the trigger with the following code instead of the above :

```
select decode(:LOAN.STATUS,'A','Active','I','Inactive') 
  into :LOAN.STATUS
  from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. When taking your advise I received an error `PRE-TEXT-ITEM trigger raised unhanled exception ORA-06502`. Would you be able to guide me. I might be doing something wrong over here.

Comment: @JeffreyJohnston It seems the length of `:LOAN.STATUS` is less than 8 in your form. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. It finally worked. I'll mark this answer in few minutes Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a value like below in the INITIAL VALUE property.

:OTHER_BLOCK.OTHER_ITEM

and by doing this, that item referenced in the INITIAL VALUE property is now like a variable.